# Почему не меняется текст после компиляции?

Tags: c#

Программист написал программу на C#. Меняю текстовые сообщение, компилирую (при помощи Visual Studio; F5), но они меняются не всегда. К примеру текст был:

```
 MessageBox.Show("Файл " + temporary + " отсутствует в списке разрешенных файлов");
```

я изменил его на:

```
 MessageBox.Show(temporary + " failas nerastas tarp leistinų failų.");
```

Текст меняется в Visual Studio и .cs файле, но в самой программе не меняется. Меняется после перезагрузки ПК и еще одной компиляции. В чем проблема?

Comment: Уточните, где вы берете исполняемый файл "самой программы"? Вы точно его перекомпилировали? Есть подозрение, что по F5 происходит только перезапуск приложения из среды разработки, но не полноценное построение exe-файла для конечного пользователя. Особенно если приложение ставится через установщик (.msi или что там сейчас популярно).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Открываю проект "launcher.sln", перехожу к файлу "Form1.cs", меняю тексты и нажимаю F5. F5 в Visual Studio означает Run, чуть правее выбрано "Release". Файл создается "\launcher\bin\x86\Release"

Comment: Ага, вот по такому описанию уже можно понять. Сожалею, у меня студии нет, но вообще тут шарпистов много, наверняка ответят )

Comment: пробовали делать rebuild перед запуском? Что говорит диспетчер задач - процесс вашего лаунчера не остается висеть в памяти после закрытия? Что студия пишет в логах компиляции? Очень похоже что исполняемый файл чем-то залочен (антивирусом?) и не может быть изменен в процессе компиляции.

Comment: @rdorn, rebuild не пробовал. Процесс не висит. При компиляции пишет, что загружает какие-то библиотеки. позже запускает программу. Ошибок и предупреждений нет. Не знаю как, но проблема решилась сама. Сейчас после каждой модификации текста он меняются и в программе

Comment: @rdorn, не помог rebuild и отключение антивируса.

Comment: *"При компиляции пишет, что загружает какие-то библиотеки. позже запускает программу."* - это не при компиляции!  Загружаемые библиотеки вы видите в разделе Debug (Отладка) окна Output (не помню по-русски). Посмотрите раздел Build (Сборка) там же.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в одной из особенностей студии, уж не знаю, баг это или фича, но некоторое количество моих нервов она в свое время мне попортила.

**Входные условия:**
В VS открыт проект по линку из списка последних открывавшихся проектов с главной станицы студии или кликом по файлу `someProject.sln`.

Случай первый:
**Действия пользователя:**
Через меню открыть->проект или кликом по файлу `otherProject.sln` в папке открываем любой другой проект.
**Реакция студии:**
Проект открывается в новом экземпляре студии, все хорошо, поведение при компиляции и запуске ожидаемое.

Случай второй:
**Действия пользователя:**
Через меню открыть->файл или кликом по файлу в папке открываем `someFile.cs`.
**Реакция студии:**
Файл открывается в новой вкладке редактора, не зависимо, принадлежит ли файл уже открытому проекту или нет. И это иногда бывает плохо.

Можно, например, открыть файл, имя которого совпадает с одним из файлов открытого проекта или открыть файл из копии проекта. При этом визуально этот, чужой для проекта, файл ни как не отличается и наличие либо отсутствие в нем ошибок не влияет ни на процесс компиляции, т.к. он в нем не участвует, ни на результат компиляции, по той же причине. Простой способ вычислить двойника, это закрыть все вкладки вообще и открыть нужные через `Обозреватель решений`.

Вообще студия не очень умеет работать с одиночными файлами, я бы сказал, вообще не умеет, только с проектами и всеми сопутствующими атрибутами. Поэтому после открытия проекта, я категорически рекомендую пользоваться исключительно `Обозревателем решений` для открытия файлов с исходным кодом.