# Атрибут Obsolete

Tags: c#, .net

Коллеги, кто может подсказать, почему билд не падает при использовании метода помеченного так:
(Infastructure.csproj)

```
[Obsolete("blah blah blah", true)]
public override int SaveChanges()
```

Метод располагается в Class Lib, вызываю в консольке. Для методов помеченных атрибутом в консольке билд ломается...
Вызов такой (TestApp.csproj):

```
var ctx = new TestContext();
ctx.TestType.Add(new TestType { Value = "qwe" });
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Переезд проекта в другую студию так же не помог.

[Ссылка на Solution](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtLfR-cVdRS-hLAcFRLfd8xDwTMLLA)

Comment: включите обработку ворнингов как ошибок и упадет. Obsolete генерирует предупреждение что метод устарел, но не запрещает его использование. Это нужно если вы планируете удалить метод в следующих релизах

Comment: @rdorn включенный флаг как раз должен давать ошибку, в этом вопрос.

Comment: @andreycha да, проглядел флажок

Comment: Не совсем так, я не планирую исключать эти методы, они есть в базовом классе, я просто хочу запретить их использование коллегами, для этого метода определена альтернатива с параметрами. Если я включаю обработку Warning'ов как ошибок, то билд падает по той причине, что переопределение прячет not obsolete методы, а ошибка должна генерироваться при вызове этих методов...

Comment: версия студии какая?

Comment: @rdorn Enterprise 2015 U3

Comment: Самое интересное, что на Community U3 атрибут работает как нужно(

Comment: у меня работает и там и там...

Comment: не может быть следствием этого? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526478/198316

Comment: Не, я одиночные *.cs, *.config, etc... Открываю VS Code. Грешу на Code Analisys... Хотя уже натыкал все как было

Comment: Ну тогда подождем, может кто еще отзовется

Comment: Стоп, а метод где-то вызывается? или просто помечен но не вызывается ни где?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47087/discussion-between-rdorn-and-kimaman2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

кхм... MSDN на эту тему молчит, но опытным путем удалось выяснить следующее:

Допустим имеем такую примитивную иерархию классов

```
class A
{
    public virtual void foo() { }
}

class B : A
{
    [Obsolete("don't use it", true)]
    public override void foo() { }
}
```

Тогда возникает Warning

> Предупреждение CS0809  Член с атрибутом "obsolete" "B.foo()" переопределяет член без атрибута "obsolete" "A.foo()"

И данный атрибут просто игнорируется в дальнейшем, несмотря на явное указание генерировать ошибку.

Не претендую на истину, но имею большие основания полагать, что в данном случае студия ведет себя корректно, потому что такой прием по сути равноценен попытке понизить уровень доступа в классе наследнике, а это нарушение принципа строго расширяющего наследования в ООП. Так что либо нужно помечать устаревшим метод базового класса, что в вашем случае невозможно, либо применить другой способ изоляции, например инкапсулировать объект класса-наследника в класс-оболочку, в которой предоставить только нужные методы, но сам класс-оболочка не должен наследоваться ни от базового, ни от производного, проблемных классов.

Comment: К сожалению вы абсолютно правы, можно попробовать задекорировать методы атрибутами и подавить предупреждение CS0809, буду придумывать... P.S. Иногда очень сожалею что в C# нет приватного наследования, на крайний случай заверну в фасад, как нибудь) Спасибо

Comment: @kimaman2 Подавление не спасет, там конфликт возникает как если заменить public на private в наследнике, но атрибуты, в отличие от модификаторов можно игнорировать, что студия и делает..

Comment: Значит только фасад, к сожалению... Но ничего и с этим жить можно...